# Show popup only with a specific zoom level

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping, popup, zoom

On my map I've a point vector that is showed as heatmap down to one a specific zoom level, after this I show the points normally.

```
var geoBlogHeatmap = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
  title: 'Heatmap',
  source: sourceGeoBlog,
  opacity: 0.8,
  renderMode: 'vector',
  gradient: ['#253494', '#2c7fb8', '#41b6c4', '#a1dab4', '#ffffcc'],
  blur: 20,
  radius: 20,
  shadow: 250,
  minZoom: 8,
  maxZoom: 13,
});

var geoBlog = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceGeoBlog,
  style: styleFunction,
  minZoom: 12,
  maxZoom: 18,
});
```

I've used the [official Popup example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html) for show a popup after a click on a feature.

```
/**
 * Elements that make up the popup.
 */
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

/**
 * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
 */
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  },
});

/**
 * Add a click handler to hide the popup.
 * @return {boolean} Don't follow the href.
 */
 closer.onclick = function() {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

var feature_onClick;
map.on('click', function(evt) {

    feature_onClick = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        // console.log(feature);
        return feature;
      });

  if (feature_onClick) {
    // console.log(feature_onClick.getProperties().pk);
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
     content.innerHTML =
     '<h3 class="text-center">'+ feature_onClick.getProperties().title + '</h3>'
     + '<hr>'
     + '<p>' + feature_onClick.getProperties().description + '</p>'
     + '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="'+ feature_onClick.getProperties().url + '">Approfondisci</a>'
     + '<hr>'
     + '<small class="text-muted"> Pubblicato: ' + feature_onClick.getProperties().time_since_publication + '</small>'
     }
});
```

I would like to see the popup only when I can see the points, then from `minZoom: 12`. How I can do this?

Comment: Simply at the beginning of `click` processing function test if `map.getView().getZoom()` is smaller than 12, and if it so, `return`.

Comment: Is not clear for me, my skill with OpenLayers and JavaScript are low. Can you write an example? If you answer my question I can vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is check in your `click` event processing function if current zoom level `map.getView().getZoom()` is lower than 12, and if it is, immediately return.

Code could then look something like this:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  if (map.getView().getZoom() < 12) return;

  feature_onClick = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
  .
  .
  .
```